# Cant find a mail id is bounced or not at the time of mail send using php

Tags: php

I want to send bulk mails .Trying to find perticular mail id is bounced or not using php.These is my code.

```
<?php
$to  = 'test@test1.com,test5@test.com';
$subject = 'iest IT test';
$message = "Namegfhgfh"; 
$content='admin@test.com';
$Headers = "From:$content\r\n" . 
"Reply-To: $content \r\n" . 
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n"; 
$Headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
$bounce='-f bounce@tes.com';
$mail=mail($to,$subject, $message, $Headers,$bounce);
if($mail)
 {
   echo "send";
 }
else
{
  echo "not send";
}
?>
```

Want to store the mail id in database,I dont know how check a mail id bounced or not, ie check a mail id is excist or not using php?Any body help me?

Comment: PHP’s `mail` does not actually _send_ the mail, but only passes it on to the MTA – so there is _no way_ to determine at this point already whether or not the mail will bounce _later_.

Comment: @CBroe MTA means?Any way to to store bounced mail  id to database?

Comment: [Message/Mail Transfer Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)

Comment: Any way to add bounced mail id in to database?